# How to retrieve additional details from db when eventclick is raised

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I have a PHP Bootstrap web page.  At load time, I generate all JSON events properties using PHP doing a MySQL query and then the fullcalendar is displayed after.

This fullcalendar contains different kinds of calendar events (each calendar event being a table with different columns) and when `eventclick()` is raised, I display a modal bootstrap form showing the event details.  The event modal is different based on an event property type.  Doing this allows me to edit via 
a form each calendar event, update the DB and refresh the fullcalendar after.

I tried initially to load all different events details (and therefore all table columns) into the fullcalendar but now, of course, there is a performance impact (on page load).

Is there a way to load a minimal set of calendar event properties (date and event title), show the fullcalendar and based on `eventclick()` retrieve additional database details before displaying the modal and allow the end user to edit the form? (the form processing after is, of course, usual PHP/MySQL code).

Thanks a lot

Comment: yes, you can use AJAX for that

Comment: Hi again, so you mean depending of the calendar event type, execute a specific  AJAX php/mysql query, fill the modal hidden fields and display the modal ? thanks again.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Thanks so much.  I did it that way and it works!